# ESlint issue "Each then should return a value or throw" while reading from google cloud store using firebase in node.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, eslint

I wanted to write a simple node.js code to read and write from the cloud store. 
I am using the following sample as my base project https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore
and added the following function by looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data
I added a names collection manually from https://console.firebase.google.com

So this is the function I added

```
exports.readMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
        var docRef = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc("Names");
        var getDoc = docRef.get()
            .then(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    console.log('No such document!');
                } else {
                    res.json({
                        result: doc.data()
                    });
                    console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting document', err);
            });
```

The code works perfectly when I deploy using firebase deploy however in my IDE which is VS Code I see an error that "Each then should return a value or throw:".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply add a `return null;` statement so the readMessage should have been as follows

```
exports.readMessage = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
            var docRef = await admin.firestore().collection('messages').doc("Names");
            var getDoc = docRef.get()
                .then(doc => {
                    if (!doc.exists) {
                        console.log('No such document!');
                    } else {
                        res.json({
                            result: doc.data()
                        });
                        console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
                    }
                    return null;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error getting document', err);
                });
```